# Can not getPrice for product

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, price

I am working on a connector module for a custom CMS system into Magento.  I am using the following code to pull the products from a given category.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catID);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
$products = $collection->getItems();

foreach ($products as $product) {...}
```

The problem is when I execute $product->getPrice() I get nothing back.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are selecting only these 3 attributes(name,description,image) then how do you expect price from the product collection. kindly add price attribute to your select.

```
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
```

and then use

```
     //returns price which is not a final one.
     $product->getPrice();
```

Comment: Duh, thanks.  I suppose we can leave this for the next person who makes this same mistake.

Comment: @Nathan Bunney yes dude it would be helpful

Comment: If you need the final or minimal price, you can add those using addMinimalPrice and addFinalPrice on the collection, as is done by Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection